# "multipled definition of b1" even though guards are active

Tags: c++

I searched around and none of the solutions seem to work with me.
I'm trying an ADT approach to organize my project, but I'm getting

> multiple definition of b1

I have 4 files:

1. main.cpp
2. myLibrary.cpp
3. myLibrary.h
4. menu.cpp

Inside main.cpp I have this code:

```
#include "myLibrary.h"
#include "menu.cpp"

int main()
{
    mainMenu();
}
```

Inside myLibrary.cpp I have:

```
#include "myLibrary.h"
///Here I have the content of the functions
```

Inside myLibrary.h I have:

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
#define MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED

struct button
{
public:
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    bool over = 0;
};
#endif
```

Inside menu.cpp I have:

```
#include "myLibrary.h"
button b1;
inline void mainMenu()
{
    b1.x1 = 100;
    b1.x2 = 200;
    b1.y1 = 100;
    b1.y2 = 200;

    draw(b1);
}
```

Comment: According to the one definition rule, no object can be defined more than once in a program. In your case, b1 is defined twice in the main and menu translation units, and hence the error. You may also want to reconsider including .cpp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
#include "menu.cpp"
```

You should never include a .cpp file.  Only headers should be included.